# [Storyboard TabController Error]

Tags: ios, storyboard, tabbarcontroller

I have a problem with tabbarcontroller.Im working with storyboard and Im using navigation controller between tabbarcontroller and viewcontroller.and also i have login page..From login page, i want to go directly to viewcontroller which is 2.tabbarcontroller..But when im doing this i cant see tabbar controller..What can be the problem? What is your suggestion?

```
  self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_bar_bkg.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont,
      nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: The segue from your login page should go to the Tab Bar Controller in your Storyboard.  Is that how you have it set up?  What kind of segue are you using (modal, push, other?) between the login screen and the next screen?

Comment: I have tried this as well ..I mean with push segue go to tabbar..But it wasnt worked?  for login screen im not using and segue...i have just call with code. but my problem i dont know such a problem that when im logged in i can see tabbar..but when im calling the the page that i want without logged in,I can not see my tabbarcontroller there???

Comment: A push segue can only be used with a navigation controller.  Is your login screen in a navigation controller.  If not, use the modal segue.

Comment: I have used login in navigation controller with push segue.. And also i tried to do that with login (without navigation controller) with modal segue ..But i didnt work? :/

My tabbarcontroller is connected to viewcontroller in navigation controller..I dont know this can be a hint to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution for this. The problem was instead of  using this:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I have used that one:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]
```

Thank you so much for your help...